# Prevent from Revert to Default Template When Some Changes are Made in Page

Tags: wordpress, templates, elementor

I'm working with Elementor, When I select my own template, from wp-admin, for a page and make some changes to that page and update that page, I see(in wp-admin) that my page has reverted to the default template, while when I created that page I selected my own created template.

How can I stop the page from reverting to the default template when I make some changes to that page.

```
<?php 
/**
    Template name: Master Template  
*/
wp_head();
get_header();
?>

<body>
    
<?php 
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
</body>

<?php 
get_footer();
wp_footer();
?>
```